# Backbone collection fetch render runs twice with router on first load

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am fairly new to Backbone and am trying to get my head around routers and calling a collection from a database.

I have the following 
Collection:

```
var Scorecards = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model:Scorecard,
 url:"http://localhost:3002/api/scorecards",

initialize:function(){
  this.fetch({
    success: this.fetchSuccess,
    error: this.fetchError
  });
},

fetchSuccess: function (collection, response) {
  console.log("results");
  if(collection.length>0) {
    var view = new ScorecardsView({el:'#scorecards-container', model:scorecards});
    view.render();
  }
  else{
    var view = new NoScorecardsView({el:'#scorecards-container'});
    view.render();
  }

},

fetchError: function(collection, response) {
  throw new Error("Failed to get scorecards");
}
});
```

Router:

```
var ScorecardRouter = Backbone.Router.extend ({ 
routes: { 
  '' : 'home', 
  'create': 'createScorecard',
  'edit': 'editScorecard'
},

home: function () { 
  console.log("Home view");
  var view = new ScorecardsView({el:'#scorecards-container', model:scorecards});
  view.render();     
}, 
createScorecard: function () { 
  console.log('Create view');
  var view = new CreateScorecardView({el:'#scorecards-container'});
  view.render();
}
});
```

Scorecards view:

```
var ScorecardsView = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function(){
  this.model.on('destroy', this.render, this);
},

render: function() {
  console.log("Scorecard render");
  var self = this;

  this.$el.html(ScorecardContTemp);
  this.model.each(function(scorecard){
    var scorecardView = new ScorecardView({model:scorecard});
    self.$('.scorecards-items tbody').append(scorecardView.render().$el);
  });
},

events: {
  "click #scorecard-create-btn" : "createScorecardView",
},

createScorecardView: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  scorecardRouter.navigate('create', {trigger: true});
}
});
```

and I start things off with this

```
  var scorecards = new Scorecards; 
  var scorecardRouter = new ScorecardRouter(); 
  Backbone.history.start();
```

My problem is, when I first hit the home route, I'm getting the view render function running twice. Because firstly the fetch is calling it and also the route is calling it.

I need to remove the call from either the fetch success or the route, but when I do I get no results on initial load and I have to navigate to a different route and back to.

How are you supposed to achieve this? So I can fetch the results once and then display them via the route the fetch is successful but also show them in the route when a user navigates to it.

I hope that makes sense?

Any help would be great.

Comment: I see that your view is not really attached to the collection. why not using `listenTo`, and render the view whenever a change to the collection was made?

Comment: Hi, do you have an example of that?

Comment: yes. I havn't tried your code or something, but personally I'd use this technique and not render the view in the router...it would look like that: (on view initialize) `this.listenTo(this.collection, "change add remove", this.render);` or something like that. Obviously you need to pass the collection when creating the view : `var myView = new View({collection:collection});`

Comment: Hi, I have added  `this.collection.bind('change add remove', this.render, this);` to my view. When inspecting the console though, its printing a console.log 5 times, the number of models in the collection. So its firing as each one gets added...

Comment: obviously, since "add" event is fired whenever a model is added to the collection. this is useful when the collection is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your data shouldn't know how it is rendered, so `new View()` anywhere within a Model or a Collection is a sure sign of a problem. Your views should watch their data and update themselves.

Your other possible source of confusion is passing `{trigger: true}` to your router `navigate` method. What kind of trouble that brings is elaborately explained in this classic Backbone article: [Don’t Execute A Backbone.js Route Handler From Your Code](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/28/dont-execute-a-backbone-js-route-handler-from-your-code/).

For now, you definitely should remove the view rendering from the collection. Instead, your view should be aware of the collection and update itself when the data changes.

Here's an example of how I would setup my view to watch the collection:

```js
/** Scorecard model */
var Scorecard = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: '',
    email: ''
  }
});

/** Scorecard View (I know it totally doesn't look like a scorecard, just an example view)  */
var ScorecardView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template('<%=name%>, <em><%=email%></em>'),
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
    return this;
  }
});

/** Collection */
var Scorecards = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Scorecard,
  
  /** using fake api for the sake of this example to work */
  url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",

  initialize:function(){
    this.fetch({
      success: this.fetchSuccess,
      error: this.fetchError
    });
  },

  fetchSuccess: function (collection, response) {
    console.log("results:", collection);
  },

  fetchError: function(collection, response) {
    throw new Error("Failed to get scorecards");
  }
});


/** Scorecards view: */

var ScorecardsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.collection.on('destroy', this.render, this);
    
    /** render one added item whenever it comes to collection */
    this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
  },

  render: function() {
    console.log("Scorecard render");
    
    /** clean the items container, 
        which will be useful when items get destroyed
        and we'll want to re-render whole collection */
    this.$el.find('.scorecards-items').empty();
    
    /** in case collection already has data, let's render it */
    this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
  },
  addOne: function(scorecard){
    var scorecardView = new ScorecardView({ model: scorecard });
    this.$('.scorecards-items').append(scorecardView.render().$el);
  }
});


/** Router: */

var ScorecardRouter = Backbone.Router.extend ({ 
  routes: { 
    '' : 'home'
  },
  home: function () { 
    console.log("Home view");
    var view = new ScorecardsView({
      el:'#scorecards-container',
      collection: scorecards
    });
    view.render();     
  }
});


/** starting things off */

var scorecards = new Scorecards(); 
var scorecardRouter = new ScorecardRouter(); 
Backbone.history.start();
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>

  <div id="scorecards-container">
    <div class="scorecards-items"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I fully agree with your answer but I'd really appreciate some code examples/snippets on the first/last paragraph.

Comment: Okay, I will add example.

Comment: Very well said! Ive been trying to recreate this code in a jsfiddle so i can see what the issue is, and there is just too much code missing (html mostly) can we start telling people to make jsfiddle code samples?! WITH an example of what the output from the model/collection is too.

Comment: Yeah, I'm recreating this case to make it work too and making up the missing parts :)

Comment: @try-catch-finally the view should bind to the data, not the other way around. in the view you do `this.on('change', this.render)` and somewhere else you would do `model/collection.fetch()`; (hard to do examples in comments :/)